# Dividing values with units

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, heat, units

I'm reading about the subject of heat in a basic physics book.  If I am not mistaken the formula to work out how much energy is required to increase the temperature of water is

```
e = M * t * shc
```

Where

- e is energy in Joules
- M is mass in kg
- t is temperature to increase by in °C
- shc is specific heat capacity in J/kg°C

If I need to solve how much the temperature has varied I rearrange the equation like this...

```
t = e / M / shc
```

And this is where I get stuck.

- e = 7.2 * 10<sup>8</sup> J
- M = 10<sup>5</sup> kg
- shc = 4.2<sup>3</sup> J/kg°C

What is the resulting unit of measurement of the following?

```
e / M = ?
M / shc = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write it out like this:

$t = \frac{e}{\frac{m}{shc}}= \frac{J}{\frac{kg}{\frac{J}{kg\cdot{}^\circ{}C}}} = \frac{J}{J \cdot kg \cdot \frac{1}{kg\cdot^{\circ}C}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{^{\circ}C}} = ^{\circ}{\rm{}C}$

Comment: This was the explanation I found easiest to understand, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When multiplying or dividing units, all you need to do is put the units in the numerator or denominator (wherever they appeared) of the answer. So:

$$[e/M]={J\over kg}$$
$$[M/shc]={kg\over{J\over kg^oC}}={kg^2\,^{\circ}\rm C\over J}$$

But this is not the correct way of analyzing your units. You have
$t = e / M / shc = e / (M * shc)$

The units of this are:
$$[t]={J\over kg {J\over kg\,^{\circ}\rm C}}=\,^{\circ}\rm C$$

Comment: Wow, Jim. Apparently your answer was so good that two different people decided to post different halves of your answer afterwards.

Comment: @Dan Indeed. But everyone is entitled to answer in their own way, so let's not have inflammatory comments like that anymore. Okay?